# Bitwise operation in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, operators, bitwise-operators

I have a column CategoryId that will store more than one value at the time, some of them have 1 (BA), 2 (SA) or 3 (both). I'm not sure if this is the right way.

For example the query down brings all records because 3 includes 1 and 2. If I want rows that have **both** categories then bitwise does not work. I believe I'm confusing terms.

Sample data and query:

```
CREATE TABLE #Payment (Id INT, Name NVARCHAR(50), CategoryId INT)

INSERT #Payment (Id, Name, CategoryId) VALUES(1, N'A', 1) --BA
INSERT #Payment (Id, Name, CategoryId) VALUES(1, N'B', 2) --SA
INSERT #Payment (Id, Name, CategoryId) VALUES(1, N'C', 3) --BA and SA
INSERT #Payment (Id, Name, CategoryId) VALUES(1, N'D', 2) --SA

DECLARE @Value INT = 3

SELECT *
FROM #Payment
WHERE (CategoryId & @Value) = CategoryId
```

Comment: What is your question again?

Comment: I need to get the ones that have only both categories in one case, thank you

Comment: See my answer. What you have checks for _any_ bit, not all.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a subtle correction needed in the WHERE clause. It should be:

```
WHERE (CategoryID & 3) =  3          -- bits 1 and 2 are set (matches 3, 7, 11, 15, ...)
```

For completeness here are the other variations:

```
WHERE (CategoryID & 3) <> 0          -- bits 1 or  2 are set (matches 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, ...)
WHERE (CategoryID & 3) =  0          -- bits 1 and 2 are not set (matches 0, 4, 8, 12, ...)
WHERE (CategoryID & 3) =  CategoryID -- bits other than 1 and 2 are not set (matches 0, 1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: This answers the question, but it seems like an X Y problem for the OP to me. Storing multiple values in one column does not seem to have any benefit here, just adding complexity. I have seen solutions which use base 2 directly in integer columns for this purpose, but they always seem clunky to query, and obfuscate data from anyone who has to support the system. Anyway, the solution works, but OP should consider something different IMO.

Comment: Sorry Jacob, what do you propose instead in this case?

Comment: May be worth noting an example using bit 3 or higher to demonstrate the exponential nature of the `(CategoryID & x)`